# NuxtJS asyncData ui not updating by the responses

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am new to **NuxtJS**.I am working on a sample project. I have a route in my project called   **pages-->post-->_id.vue** . I am trying to run a sample code just to test fetching with API with asyncData. But when I hit the URL http://localhost:3000/post/2 , not thing shows up on UI. Here is my code in **_id.vue.**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Post</h1>
    <div v-if="post" id="first-post">
      <h4> HELLO </h4>
      <h3 class="text-lg">{{ post.title }}</h3>
      <p class="text-base">{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    const { data } = await $axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.id}`);
    return { post: data };
  },
   data() {
    return {
      post:{
        'title':'Test Post',
        'body':'Lorem ipsum'
      }
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I watched some videos/lessons on the internet with the same code working with their project. I need help regarding this issue.
Thank You

Comment: Are there any errors printed on the console or the terminal? How did you register the Axios plugin?

Comment: its showing 500 internal server error on the route

Comment: 1. npm install @nuxtjs/axios 2.nuxt.config.js --> modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']